# No Mapping GET for URI.json format

Tags: json, spring, rest

i don't know why occured no mapping for GET Message for URI.json..

[image: first image]

but good working well without '.json'

[image: second image]

and i tried used MockMvc Test in Junit4.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class WriteActionControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WriteActionController writeActionController;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp()
    {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(writeActionController).build();

    }

    @Test
    void getCommentsList() throws Exception {

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = 
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/view/2/comments.json").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());
    }
```

This code has SpringController.class

```
@RestController
public class WriteActionController {


    @GetMapping("/view/{postNumber}/comments")
    public List<CommentsDTO> getCommentsList(@PathVariable int postNumber){
        return viewService.select_CommentsByPostNumber(postNumber);
    }

}
```

But, I got this Successful ResponseMessage when used MockMvcTest in Junit4.
I wanna answer why doesn't the GET request to that work on browser

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /view/2/comments.json
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
         Body = <no character encoding set>
Session Attrs = {}




MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 200
       Error message = null
       Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
       Content type = application/json
       Body = [{"comments_id":1,"comments_content":"hello world","_usr_email":"admin","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"},{"comments_id":2,"comments_content":"test","_usr_email":"admin","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"},{"comments_id":3,"comments_content":"uytyu","_usr_email":"admin","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"},{"comments_id":4,"comments_content":"tewqwes","_usr_email":"admin","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"},{"comments_id":5,"comments_content":"testtest","_usr_email":"mokaim@naver.com","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"},{"comments_id":6,"comments_content":"testtest","_usr_email":"mokaim@naver.com","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"},{"comments_id":7,"comments_content":"test","_usr_email":"admin","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"},{"comments_id":8,"comments_content":"wewer","_usr_email":"admin","_post_num":2,"reg_date":"2020-07-26"}]
      Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
      Cookies = []
```

Comment: Because your test and actual code are different. You should autowire the `MockMvc` to get the same results as that will reuse the actual web configuration, your config will create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I am not quite sure if I get your question. Is the question about the RequestMapping? So you have this Controller here:

```
@GetMapping("/view/{postNumber}/comments")
```

So your application only listen in `comments` and not on `comments.json`. You can add more than one value to the mapping if needed.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/view/{postNumber}/comments", "/view/{postNumber}/comments.json"})
```

Here also [Baeldung Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) that gives awesome explanation about Spring.